Docker container can't connect to SQL Server on a local server
I am trying to containerise a .NET framework 2.0 legacy application connecting to SQL Server on localhost outside the Docker, I am able to containerise the application but it doesn't connect to SQL Server.
Even I comment out the connection string from the web.config, it tries to connect to SQL Server and I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
ARG source

EXPOSE 1433 //SQL-Server port

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*
RUN Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-ASP; Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-ISAPI-Ext

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service ;New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\software\microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force; Set-Service -Name wmsvc -StartupType automatic;
RUN Install-WindowsFeature web-server, web-webserver
RUN Import-Module WebAdministration;Import-Module ServerManager

RUN New-Item c:/msi -ItemType Directory
RUN powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/D/E/DDE57C26-C62C-4C59-A1BB-31D58B36ADA2/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi -OutFile c:/inetpub/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi
RUN powershell -Command Start-Process c:/inetpub/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait

RUN New-Item -ItemType directory -Path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\RAFTS\Test\Admin' 

RUN Import-Module WebAdministration; New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site 'Default Web Site' -Name 'Admin' -PhysicalPath "c:\inetpub\wwwroot"

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot/RAFTS/Test/Authentication
COPY authentication/. .

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY admin/. .

RUN cmd /c icacls C:/inetpub/wwwroot /grant:r Everyone:F /t

My connection string in web.config:
<!--<add
    key = "***.Data.ConnectionString"
    value = "Server=****, 1433; Database=***;User ID=***;Password=***;" />-->

I have tried using host.docker.internal in the connection string:
<!--<add
    key = "Stopford.RAFTS.Data.ConnectionString"
    value = "Data Source=host.docker.internal,1433; Database=***;User ID=***;Password=****;" />-->

but I am unable to ping host.docker.internal so there is no use of using in connection string.
My main worry is despite there is no reference to SQL connection after I commented all the connection references in web.config, the code is still looking to connect to SQL Server.
Any help would be great.

Have you installed SQL on the same machine where you run the container? From where (container or host) do you ping? Have you enabled the TCP on SQL Server? Have you checked the TCP connection from your host? Try with host-gateway or the IP instead of host.docker.internal

The machine running SQL Server believes it is localhost; the container also believes it is localhost, but a different localhost.  Saying the database is "on localhost" is true but doesn't mean anything.  Where is it actually running?  Have you read through this question on reaching non-container processes on the same host?

@Max , yes the sql server is on the same local machine, and the .net application can access the sqlserver when I run it from the IIS locally. Also, I can connect to local sqlserver using localhost, and the ip.  I can't ping either host.docker.internal nor host-gateway. The strange thing is, even I comment out the connection string, still the container looks for the sqlserver and throwing -  (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server error

@DavidMaze I totally understand that container run in its on isolated space within the container and doesn't have accessibility outside its scope unless we expose the port. Think of a scenario, sqlserver running on your laptop and your traditional .net app accessing the sqlserver server through a connection string configured in a web.config.  continued......

@DavidMaze Now, since there is no windows sqlserver image available and I can't containerise the .network framework on linux container, I have containerised this app on windows container and trying to access sqlserver which is outside the container, installed locally on the laptop through the app which is in the container. Hope this helps

Aside... EXPOSE 1433 in the Dockerfile is meaningless for a web application container unless your web application happens to be listening for incoming connections on port 1433.

As I mentioned, the thing which puzzles me that how come, the container is still looking for sqlserver when I have commented the connection string.

Since you're using a server core image, have you tried using Test-NetConnection -ComputerName host.docker.internal -Port 1433 (from the NetTCPIP module) to see if there is connectivity?

@AlwaysLearning I understand what you meant, I was trying to experiment lots of things after reading different posts and solutions provided by people on containerising .net framework apps and I stuck with the sqlserver server, so I forgot to remove the unwanted code. Thanks for pointing out. s there any documentation available for Test-NetConnection -ComputerName host.docker.internal -Port 1433, I have never read anyone suggesting this as a solution.

Test-NetConnection for PowerShell environments.

@AlwaysLearning Test-NetConnection -ComputerName host.docker.internal -Port 1433 yields this error WARNING: Name resolution of host.docker.internal failed -- Status: No such host is known

You aren't running that on the Docker host are you? If you are getting that error when running it from inside the Docker container then it sounds like your Docker embedded DNS is broken.

@AlwaysLearning I am running this on the Docker host (PowerShell). If you say Docker embedded DNS is broken, how to fix that. Any ideas?

You should be running it inside the container, so open a terminal to container and run the command from there.

@AlwaysLearning I get this result after running inside the container terminal
ComputerName     : host.docker.internal RemoteAddress    : 192.168.1.21 RemotePort       : 1433 InterfaceAlias   : WiFi SourceAddress    : 192.168.1.21 TcpTestSucceeded : True

So then it resolves correctly and Server=host.docker.internal,1433; should work in your connection string... when running INSIDE your container.

It's still not working. Please check my connection
<add  key = "**.**.Data.ConnectionString"     value = "Data Source=host.docker.internal,1433;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**" />
Error:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time)

@AlwaysLearning  @DavidMaze, I further dug the IIS application logs in the docker and I found, it throws this error while trying to authenticate. Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid. This means, it is able to reach SQL Server but causing some other issue. Any ideas, on this error.

You should ask a new question about that, it's not anything to do with SQL Server. Forms authentication running inside Docker containers is likely going to have issues because of differing machine keys invalidating logins.

@AlwaysLearning Yes sure. I will do that but could you point me in the right direction as what I should be doing to resolve the machine keys invalidating logins

I further dug the IIS application logs in the docker and I found, it throws this error while trying to authenticate.
Event code: 4005
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.
Event time: 29/07/2024 17:02:30
Event time (UTC): 29/07/2024 16:02:30
Event ID: 35ad1e99c62b4667b240c19a0c3e945f
Event sequence: 2
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 50201

Application information:
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-133667425492016462
    Trust level: Full
    Application Virtual Path: /
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
    Machine name: EC7A5C0027E8

Process information:
    Process ID: 2624
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Request information:
    Request URL: http://localhost/default.aspx
    Request path: /default.aspx
    User host address: 192.168.1.21
    User:
    Is authenticated: False
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Name to authenticate:

Custom event details:

